# HAProxy: Possible to dynamically construct new headers based on the HTTP request?

Tags: haproxy

I'd like to create a header that contains the full URL of the request. So for example:

```
reqadd X-Request-URL:\ ${X-Forwarded-Proto}:\/\/${Host}${Path}
```

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. The header manipulation configuration commands only support adding or substituting in static strings, not dynamic variables. HAProxy remains relatively lightweight in this way in order to keep it's speed up.

Comment: I'd add that it's expected to be possible in a next version, but not too soon as some changes are still necessary.